# What is the more efficient way to edit this code to avoid killing performance?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

Using Facebook FQL question I want to show the messages from a list of pages I admin on Facebook. I have set all the permissions right. So, for one page

`SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 260781667265525`

I get the last posts.
Because I want to avoid 1 question for every page I tried this without a luck. Maybe FB does not allow it.

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (260781667265525,144001959017107,126981654044612,245831082115900)
```

What I want to achieve is a better-performance written code but I guess I have to exclude `IN` (in case that I am correct with the above query).

The part of my code I am trying to include the *latest posts* in every page is below.

```
$pagesFanCounts = $facebook->api("/fql", array(
  "q" => "SELECT page_id, name, fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id IN ({$pagesIds})"
));

   foreach ($pagesFanCounts['data'] as $page){
      echo "{$page['name']} - {$page['fan_count']} fans", '<br />';
   }

// names + fans are printed correctly. My goal is to add 2-3 of the latest posts of every page


$latestPosts= $facebook->api("/fql", array("q" => "SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 260781667265525 LIMIT 2 "));
   foreach ($latestPosts['data'] as $post){
      echo "{$post['message']}", '<br />';
   }
```

Comment: Not a solution as such but maybe you can group these into a batch request as detailed here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually 'IN' queries are very expensive.  You might be better off using WHERE source_id IS '$source1' OR source_id IS '$source2' ... and so on.

Another way to have good performance is to run queries individually and add them together programmatically.  Sometimes this can give you better performance.

```
$result = array();
foreach( $pagesIds as $id) {
  $pagesFanCounts = $facebook->api("/fql", array(
  "q" => "SELECT page_id, name, fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id IS $id"
  ));
  $result[] = $pagesFanCounts['data'];
}
//now handle the data as you wish with $result
```